# foreach и запросы к базе(совсем новичок)

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь сделать выгрузку товаров из корзины магазина с помощью `PHPExcel`

```
 $export_cart_products = $_SESSION['cart']['products'];

    foreach ($export_cart_products as $key => $row) {

        $phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A$i", $row['product_id']);
        $string = $row['product'];
        $phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit("B$i", $string, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
        $phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("C$i", $row['price']);
        $phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("D$i", $row['amount']);

        $result_array = array();


        foreach ($row['product_options'] as $option_id => $variant_id) {

           $option_name = db_get_fields("SELECT option_name FROM ?:product_options_descriptions WHERE option_id = ?i", $option_id, $variant_id, CART_LANGUAGE);
           $variant_name = db_get_fields("SELECT variant_name FROM ?:product_option_variants_descriptions WHERE variant_id = ?i", $variant_id, $option_id, CART_LANGUAGE);
        };
```

__ плейсхолдеры ?: заменяются на значение cscart_

во втором `foreach` пытаюсь вывести опции товара, опции приходят в виде массива

```
array = [4] => 34, [3] => 12
```

каждый ключ и каждое значение это название "цвет", "размер", "XXL(большой размер)", "Синий", "Красный"  и т.д.
соответственно нужен запрос к базе, чтобы их вывести(подозреваю, что мой запрос к базе не совсем корректный). Сейчас получается только вариант с одной парой "Цвет: Синий" или "размер: XL", но у товара несколько таких значений(цвет, размер...).

Как сделать так, чтобы он выводил все опции товара.

Совсем запутался, а проект надо делать.
xls корректно сохраняется, только без опций, а опции нужны.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($row['product_options'] as $option_id => $variant_id) {

       $option_name = db_get_fields("SELECT option_name FROM ?:product_options_descriptions WHERE option_id = ?i", $option_id, $variant_id, CART_LANGUAGE);
       $variant_name = db_get_fields("SELECT variant_name FROM ?:product_option_variants_descriptions WHERE variant_id = ?i", $variant_id, $option_id, CART_LANGUAGE);
    };
```

Здесь в цикле перезаписыватся значения и будет получено только одно на выходе, как ни крути.

Должен сохраняться массив, если нужен массив. Например так:

```
       foreach ($row['product_options'] as $option_id => $variant_id) {

       $option_name[] = db_get_fields("SELECT option_name FROM ?:product_options_descriptions WHERE option_id = ?i", $option_id, $variant_id, CART_LANGUAGE);
       $variant_name[] = db_get_fields("SELECT variant_name FROM ?:product_option_variants_descriptions WHERE variant_id = ?i", $variant_id, $option_id, CART_LANGUAGE);
    };
```

Но может быть лучше использовать ассоциативный массив с foreach для записи значений или цикл for с индексами с массивом.

Вот пример с ассоциативным:

```
       foreach ($row['product_options'] as $option_id => $variant_id) {

       $option_name = db_get_fields("SELECT option_name FROM ?:product_options_descriptions WHERE option_id = ?i", $option_id, $variant_id, CART_LANGUAGE);
       $variant_name = db_get_fields("SELECT variant_name FROM ?:product_option_variants_descriptions WHERE variant_id = ?i", $variant_id, $option_id, CART_LANGUAGE);

     $options[] = ['option_name' => $option_name, 'variant_name' => $variant_name];
    };
```

Тут в зависимости как нужно дальше обрабатывать массив.

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению он почему-то все равно получает одну пару ключ => значение, т.е. цвет => синий, а у данного товара есть еще и размер, вот я их вместе никак не выведу.

Comment: Как вы проверяете, что выводит массив после обработки?

Comment: такой массив приходит при распечатке

$fn_print_die($row['product_options']);
Array([4] => 18,[3] => 13)
где 4 - цвет, 3 - размер, соответственно 18 и 13 значения

Comment: проверяю fn_print_die($options)

Comment: сложно ответить не видя код после обработки цикла. если вы еще не решили проблему, то напишите цикл полностью или хотя бы те месте, где происходит полная обработка данных и сохранение критериев товара